# Hazelcast: What would be the implications of adding indexes to huge existing IMaps?

Tags: performance, indexing, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

Given 4-5 nodes having many IMaps with lots of data in it, some of the predicate queries started to become significantly slow. One of the solutions for solving this performance issue (as I think) could be adding indexes. However, this data is part of a sensible system which is currently being used in production.

Before adding indexes, I was wondering what would be the consequences of doing it on huge IMaps? (would it lock the entire map ?; would it bring down the entire system?; etc.) Hazelcast documentation includes information about how to do it, but doesn't give any other explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add the index in runtime this is what will happen:

- the AddIndexOperation will be executed on every partition
- during the execution of the AddIndexOperation the partition will be blocked until all partition data are iterated and added to the index.

Queries won't be blocked in this timeframe - but get/put operations will.

I would recommend doing it in the "maintenance window" where you have the smallest load.

`lots of data` is relative - just execute a test in your dev environment having exactly the same amount of data to see how long it will take to add an index in your environment.